# VS2012 Schema compare not updating db project as target

Tags: visual-studio-2012, database-project

I have a database which I selected as source, and my current db project which I selected as target, now the schema compare shows me a table that is missing in my db project, upon clicking on update I would expect that the file is added to my project, however nothing happens. 
Do I missunderstand the purpose of this tool, or is there a bug ?

Comment: What happens if you generate a script instead of updating the project? Does it give you the schema for the table? Are you able to take that script, save it, then import it? Do you see anything in the output or SQL Data Tools windows that show any messages?  I haven't hit this problem before so wondering if there's something specific to this scenario causing an issue.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem.  When I changed visual studio to run as administrator it started working.  I guess it is some type of permissions issue even though it does not give an error of anything to indicate this.  Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

You may re-do the schema compare again. Sometimes it shows as not in the project files. I have came across the same issue some time back. What i did was, created a sql file in database project & added the create table script into that file. Couldn't find any other solution than this.